# How can I prove that a material is ferroelectric using DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, 2d-lattice, berry-phase, ferroelectric

I would like to prove that a 2D material (Say ZnO) is ferroelectric. Since Ferroelectric materials are a subset of piezoelectric materials. How should I proceed to prove that the polarization is indicative of ferroelectric nature?

[image]

One way would be to show that the spontaneous polarization is reversed by reversing the applied electric field.

But this seems not to be the case, as the [Q&A which I've found on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-does-confirm-ferroelectricity-from-Density-Functional-Theory) states :

> **How does confirm ferroelectricity from Density Functional Theory ? Question**
>
> Ferroelectric materials give spontaneous electric polarization? Is
> there any limit of polarization value for ferroelectric materials?
> How does differ (1) dielectric polarization (2) paraelectric
> polarization and (3) ferroelectric polarization on the basis of DFT
> calculations.

> **Answer**
> This is not a simple question! I will deal with the easier parts
> first.
>
> 1. Your definition of ferroelectricity is incomplete. Yes, there should be a spontaneous polarization, but it must be reversible under
>    a sufficiently large electric field.
> 2. The difference between ferroelectric polarization and dielectric or paraelectric polarisation is that in the latter two cases you need to
>    apply an electric field to observe the polarisation. The main
>    differences between paraelectric and dielectric polarization are
>    context - a paraelectric is the state just above the Curie temperature
>    of a ferroelectric material and as such will normally exhibit a
>    temperature dependence of permittivity that obeys the Curie Weiss law,
>    which is evidence of a soft phonon mode. Given the temperature
>    constraints of DFT, this is a difficult issue to address. Back to your
>    first question; with DFT you can determine whether your material has a
>    dipole moment by summing the Born effective charges in the unit cell.
>    However you need to be careful about whether you are looking a single
>    unit cell or a large supercell to determine whether the dipole moment
>    is coherent across all unit cells - that will then confirm whether you
>    have a spontaneous polarization and not an antipolar or randomly polar
>    material. BUT proving that the spontaneous polarisation is reversible
>    is the problem. Essentially the definition of a ferroelectric is a
>    phenomenological one - it relies on the observation of a field
>    reversible polarisation, which does cause some issues. In experiments,
>    you may have a material that from its crystal structure looks as
>    though it may have a spontaneous polarization, but for which the
>    coercive field is beyond the breakdown field of the material. You
>    cannot prove this is ferroelectric. However, your problem is slightly
>    different and comes down to how well equipped is your implementation
>    of DFT to calculate structures under applied electric fields, i.e. so
>    that you can prove reversibility of the dipole moment under a
>    sufficiently high field.

Apart from this is there anything I should keep in mind while working with 2D materials?

It would be nice to hear some thoughts on the same!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5):

As a good starting, you may take a look at this classical paper and its supplementary material:
https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.097601

Here I just show some general steps:

1. [Calculate the polarization](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LCALCPOL) (I assume that you can use the VASP package):
2. Calculate the $A, B, C, D$ of Landau-Ginzburg expansion:

$$E= \sum_i \dfrac{A}{2}(P_i^2)+\dfrac{B}{4}(P_i^4)+\dfrac{C}{6}(P_i^6)+\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\dfrac{D}{2}(P_i-P_j)^2 $$

3. Calculate the Curie temperature with AIMD or Monte-Carlo method (optional for your question).

Hope it helps.

Comment: a question, how to process data for AIMD? Like for the 2d material with out-of-plane polarization, should I directly extract dipolemoment from OUTCAR or find average distance? I didn't get correct result from both of these.